# How to create and consume Windows service in Java

Tags: java, windows-services

I am new in Java can you please tell me how to consume and create a windows based Service in java .Like in c# Signal R is there we consume windows service using java script .But can you please help me on JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a windows service using java you can first create a Java software that behaves like a service (a never stopping thread doing something or a server like software with an open socket expecting waiting for connections).

After you create the jar file with the Main class (check gradle application plugin for building a runnable jar file using gradle: https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-applications/)

Then you can create a bat script that runs your java jar:

```
@echo off
java -jar myjar.jar
```

Then you can use this program https://nssm.cc/ in order to create a windows service from the bat file (which runs your jar file):

```
nssm64.exe install myservice
```

An admin console will open asking you to set the exe file to run (your bat file) , then the starting path and other options:

[image: NSSM admin console]

Hope this helps

Comment: is there any simple way .I have a desktop application but if i need to convert is at a  web application .We need to create a service .

Comment: If you want to create a webapp fast using java, I recommend Spring Boot. Check this out: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ . With spring boot you can create webapps as runnable Jars. Once you have your runnable jar you can make it into a windows service by following the instructions in my answer.